# change Body Background on click jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background

I have been working over a theme for MyBB, where i am trying to implement a jQuery Background switcher.
I have been trying but not successful.

Here is html :

```
<script src="images/vhut/style/pattern.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/images/image directory/script/cookie.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="pat" id="pat1" style="background:url('images/image directory/style/patterns/pat1.jpg')">click 1</a>
<a href="#" class="pat" id="pat2" style="background:url('images/imag directory/style/patterns/pat2.jpg')">click 2</a>
```

Here is the JS file i am using :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.default').click(function(e){
        var bg = $(this).css('background');
        $('body').css('background','none')
})

$(".pat").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass('background');
    if( $('#alpha-style').is(':checked')){
            $('#alpha-style').attr("checked",false);
            $('.bg-alpha').hide();
        }
});

$("#pat1").click(function(){
$(body).css("background", "url(patterns/1.png)");
return false;
});

$("#pat2").click(function(){
$(body).css("background", "patterns/2.png)");
return false;
});
});
```

The patterns are located in a folder images/ theme directory/ style/patterns
The js file is located in images/theme directory/ style

So can anyone help regarding my code or provide a possible solution for the error i am getting
help is appreciated
regards,

Comment: have you tried looking at the browser console if there are any errors?

Comment: I would recommend not to use spaces in the folder names -- and filenames as well. change `image directory` to `image_directory` or something similar.

Comment: there are no console errors, @maan81 : the folder names i just provided here are examples, the folder name is actually vhut just for descriptive purpose i renamed them here

Answer (score 0):

Images are fetched relative to the document root, so the client is requesting resources at `example.com/patterns/1.png`.  Just because the JS folder is in your images folder doesn't mean you can use relative paths to your resources in your JS.  Just use

```
url(/images/image directory/style/patterns/1.png);
```

Also take a look at your console.  It is your best friend.  If using Chrome, Right-click and inspect element and check your network tools for 404 responses.  If using Firefox, download Firebug immediately and do the same.  It will tell you exactly the URLs that are being fetched and you can do troubleshooting in your JS to achieve the appropriate response.

Comment: i have tried it but still in vain, :( is there any easy code for this , like changing the background pattern on click with jquery

Comment: `body` should be in quotes in your event listeners, `$('body')`, not `$(body)`